# AngularJS - How to execute function in controller only once in the context of Routing

Tags: angularjs

I'm using the routing feature of AngularJS. Furthermore I want only on controller for all templates.

In my controller `angularJsController` I have an `init`function, which should only be executed at the first time the controller gets executed and when I explicitly call the function. But I don't wan't that the `init` function will be executed each time the routing loads another template.

How can I achieve the desired behaviour?

```
var app = angular.module("angularJsApplication", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
       .when("/overview", {
           templateUrl : "overview.html",
           controller : "angularJsController"
       .when("/settings", {
           templateUrl : "settings.html",
           controller : "angularJsController"
       ...
});

app.controller("angularJsController", function ($scope, $location, $http) {
  $scope.init = function() {
    //do stuff
  };
}
```

Comment: That's almost a perfect example of what angular services are for.

Comment: First, this is what services are for;  services are singletons, so they only initialize once.  Second, you should **NEVER** use the same controller for more than one route.

Comment: @Claies can you explain why you say never use the same controller for more than one route? I've done this in the past w/out issue (though not 1 controller for all my routes). Just curious, it seems perfectly acceptable to re-use a controller.

Comment: Why shouldn't I use same controller for more..?

Comment: The whole point of the MVC architecture is that you have separation of concerns.  While using the same Controller for more than one View (Route) *works*, it isn't a separated concern.  It can lead to confusion when you have functions/properties in the controller that don't even apply to the particular view, or when you try to use the same value in multiple views which end up either not being set or being reset or changed unexpectedly.

Comment: I think @Claies was just saying it's very advisable to have one controller per view (per MVC) because each view may have different functionalities and stuffing them all in a single controller isn't the best practice.

Comment: I agree that re-using the same controller in every single view will break down, become code smell, etc. in any reasonably sized application.  However, there are some cases where the views are quite simple and have more things in common than not. Re-using the controller in such a scenario seems better than duplicating code. This is why I asked b/c the blanket statement of you should never do that seemed a bit harsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a service to do the things that should only be executed once.  Services are stored as singletons, but you can provide one or more ways to re-execute code.

```
app.factory("initService", [function() {
    var returnObject = {}
    // set properties of returnObject
    // do something like this if you need "explicitly call the function"
    returnObject.recaculate = function() {
        // perform recaculations
    } 
    return returnObject;
}]);
```

Don't forget to inject the service into your controller(s):

```
app.controller("angularJsController", ["$scope", "$location", "$http", "initService", function ($scope, $location, $http, initService) {
    // controller contents
    $scope.reInit = function() {
       initService.recaculate();
    }
}]);
```